# How to debug "Unexpected debug information initialization error -- 'Failed to find a required export in the runtime.'"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm getting this error message on all projects (including brand new empty templates) I'm trying to build with Visual Studio 2008:

> Unexpected debug information initialization error
>       -- 'Failed to find a required export in the runtime.'

The [Error Help for Compiler Error CS0040](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d82598t0.aspx) is not very helpful:

> This error can occur when using the
>   /debug compiler option and indicates
>   that the compiler was unable to write
>   to the .pdb file. Possible resolutions
>   to this error include reinstalling
>   Visual Studio, ensuring that the
>   compiler has write access to a file or
>   directory, or not compiling with
>   /debug.

I can manually create files in the intended {bin,obj}\Debug directories, running the Studio as Administrator didn't help, uninstalling both the 3.5 framework and the Visual Studio 2008 and re-installed both with their respective Service Packs and I'm still getting the error.

Removing all `/debug` switches from the command line obviously removes the error message as indicated, but is no option for further development.

How can I further debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I used the [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from the [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/0e18b180-9b7a-4c49-8120-c47c5a693683.aspx) to take a look at the things the compiler was doing. By starting `csc.exe` from the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt and filtering by `Process Name is "csc.exe"` in the process monitor, I got a good picture of what the compiler was doing.

"Inspired" by the "Failed to find a required export in the runtime" message I searched for missing DLLs and actually found that `csc.exe` was trying to access `Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\diasymreader.dll` but failed. Getting that DLL from another installation fixed the error for me.

Comment: Wow thanks. I was unable to build any solution after my windows 10 machine had some kind of disk drive wobbly, and I had to do a system restore. Replacing that .dll with one from work fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you've got mismatched versions of VS/.NET DLLs somehow installed, or some bizarre "half 3.0 half 3.5" bad state that I've seen happen a few times; you could go around checking versions everywhere but it might be easiest to just pave the machine :(